# python csv writer remove carriage returns

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Can somebody helps how to remove ^M end of line ?
I am using Unix system.
This is default sample script from csv python  docu, I use similar scenario in my script with same results :(

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```

Answer (score 2):

The `^M` is the carriage-return character (`\r` - `0x0d`).

So you probably have `\r` or `\r\n` (`0x0d 0x0a`) at the end of each line.

Maybe you could try with:

```
with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as csvfile:
```

or:

```
with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='\x0a') as csvfile:
```

Comment: Hi, with `newline='\n'` I still see ^M in end of line, and with newline=0x0a i got this error >  with open('names.csv', 'w', newline=0x0a ) as csvfile:
TypeError: open() argument 6 must be str or None, not int

Comment: @andrew Ok, try newline='0x0a', or '\x0a' or maybe str(10) (I'll update the answer then). Not sure if Python understands 0x.. ) I don't know Python that well.

Comment: @andrew In general `\r\n` is a DOS newline and `\n` is a Linux one. Are you running that script on linux or DOS?

Comment: Hi Danny , this syntax worked '\x0a' but with same ^M results
..Unix

Comment: @andrew You mean in the newly created file? Are you able to look at the file in a hex editor? (or maybe upload a sample). And where do you see the `^M`?

Comment: I just looked at VI editor, yes new created file, new timestamp

Comment: hexdump> `hexdump  names.csv 
0000000 6966 7372 5f74 616e 656d 6c2c 7361 5f74
0000010 616e 656d 0a0d 6142 656b 2c64 6542 6e61
0000020 0d73 4c0a 766f 6c65 2c79 7053 6d61 0a0d
0000030 6f57 646e 7265 7566 2c6c 7053 6d61 0a0d
`

Comment: You need to get rid of the 0d in 0a0d. It's strange that it is there while using \x0a ..

Comment: anyway can u advice how post code in block format ?  seems not working as when craeting new topic

Comment: You mean in the comments? Not possible I think.

Comment: OK, here is again>
```00000000  66 69 72 73 74 5f 6e 61  6d 65 2c 6c 61 73 74 5f  |first_name,last_|
00000010  6e 61 6d 65 0d 0a 42 61  6b 65 64 2c 42 65 61 6e  |name..Baked,Bean|
00000020  73 0d 0a 4c 6f 76 65 6c  79 2c 53 70 61 6d 0d 0a  |s..Lovely,Spam..|
00000030  57 6f 6e 64 65 72 66 75  6c 2c 53 70 61 6d 0d 0a  |Wonderful,Spam..|```

Comment: Still there.. did you use '\x0a'? If yes, I wonder where the 0d comes from..

Comment: Very strange.. what happens when you use '#' as a test?

Comment: like this ?  newline='#' 
with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='#' ) as csvfile:
ValueError: illegal newline value: #

Comment: Yes , is strange, In all forums I see that `newline='' ` should fix this...

Comment: Could it be something in your default (OS) settings? But then, '\x0a' should work.. Just for fun, what with `'\r'` only?

Comment: with \r, I got all output in one line > `irst_name,last_name^M^MBaked,Beans^M^MLovely,Spam^M^MWonderful,Spam^M^M`

Comment: But where does that second ^M keep coming from then.. :) I don't have Python, so can't test. Are you using the code from your question, or does the data come from a file or database? Could it be something in DictWriter? Maybe use another form of writing? (I'm running out of options.. :)

Comment: Maybe you could write to a file step by step (first without csv or DictWriter) and each time check the hexdump for possible `0d`.

Comment: Yes. I use directly from this code. Maybe is it for bad python implementation in unix. I don't know.

Comment: Anyway thx for your effort. Don't worry about this. I have plan B :)

Comment: Ok, go for it! :)